# Vector Field with dense orbits

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, vector-fields

I'm trying solve the following problem:

Let $M$ be a manifold and $X$ be a complete $C^1$ vector field. Suppose that the foward orbit and backward orbit of every point on $M$ is dense in $M$. Then $M$ is compact.

There is any hint to this problem?.